# Proving injection and surjection based on set's elements

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $S$ and $T$ be finite sets and define the function $f:S->T$.

Assume $S$ consists of $m$ elements and that $T$ consists $n$ elements.

1) Assume $m<n$ and show that f cannot be surjective.

2) Assume $m>n$ and show that f cannot be injective.

3) Assume $m=n$, and show that f is injective if and only if it is surjective

---

Here is what I've tried:

1) I have the definition of a surjective function given by

If for all $n\in T, \exists m\in S$ such that $f(n)=m$, then f is surjective.

I'm not entirely sure how to prove it. I know that if the domain has less elements than it's codomain, then it cannot be surjective.

2) 
If for all $m\in S,f(m)=f(n)->m=n$

I know that a function is injective, if each domain maps to a single element in the codomain, and therefore if the domain has more elements than the codomain, it cannot be injective.

But I am unsure how to prove it.

3) I know $m=n$ must correspond to a bijection, as it has to be surjective and injective. But I am uncertain how to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

Denote $\langle a, b\rangle := \{n \in \Bbb Z \mid a \le n \le b\}$.

Since $S$ has $m$ elements and $T$ has $n$ elements, there is a bijection $\theta : S \to \langle 1,m \rangle$ and a bijection $\phi : T \to \langle 1,n \rangle$.

Therefore we can define the function $F : \langle 1,m \rangle \to \langle 1,n \rangle : i \mapsto \phi \circ f \circ \theta^{-1}(i)$.

Can you figure out how to prove your three results for $F$ instead of $f$? 
I.e., that for an arbitrary $F : \langle 1,m \rangle \to \langle 1,n \rangle$ if $m < n$ then $F$ is not surjective, etc. It may be useful to prove the contrapositives of the statements instead of the version given.

Once you have proved them for $F$, you can use $\theta$ and $\phi$ to also prove it for $f$.